# Python: exclude one year from data frame with DatetimeIndex using .loc[]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

Let's say I have got the following pandas.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'avg': list(range(100, 900, 100)), 'median': list(range(150, 950, 100))}, 
    index=pd.date_range('2011-12-01', periods=8, freq='3M')
)
print(df)

            avg  median
2011-12-31  100     150
2012-03-31  200     250
2012-06-30  300     350
2012-09-30  400     450
2012-12-31  500     550
2013-03-31  600     650
2013-06-30  700     750
2013-09-30  800     850
```

When I want to extract one year from data frame, I use `.loc[]` like this:

```
print(df.loc['2012'])
            avg  median
2012-03-31  200     250
2012-06-30  300     350
2012-09-30  400     450
2012-12-31  500     550
```

But when I want to exclude one year from the data frame, the only code that really works for me, is the following one:

```
print(df.loc[df.index.to_period('Y') != 2012])
            avg  median
2011-12-31  100     150
2013-03-31  600     650
2013-06-30  700     750
2013-09-30  800     850
```

It seems to me a kind of complicated, compared to the previous one, where I was selecting one year from the data frame. So, I wanted to ask, if there is another simpler solution, which I would have missed? Something like this:

```
df.loc[~ '2012']
```

Comment: It is not implemented, unfortnately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, for a slightly shorter version you have [`DatetimeIndex.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html):

```
df[df.index.year!=2012]
```